# Padrino + MongoMapper/Joint Troubles

Tags: mongomapper, padrino, gridfs

> I'm using MongoMapper with Joint on Padrino, and trying to get the
>   upload working. However, I keep getting thrown a `NoMethodError
>   "undefined method 'path' for #<Hash:0xa6fbdf0>"`. It seems like it
>   can't see the path, but the parameters are okay. What is the problem
>   here?

Gist with the code: https://gist.github.com/1323998

I was able to get it to not error, but when I go to find the file with `mongofiles`, I can't find. The same goes for rack/grid-fs. Where is Joint saving to, and is it saving at all?

Comment: Where is that error coming from? I don't see any mention of "path" in any of that code.

Comment: Joint automatically adds the `path` field into my model when I specify `attachment :file`. I assume it's trying to use that but can't.

Comment: But someone is trying to call `path` on a Hash so you need to know where the error is coming from so you can backtrack and find out why you have a Hash when someone is expecting an instance of your model.

Comment: Done. Looks to be a MM issue.

Comment: Looks like it is getting called here https://github.com/jnunemaker/joint/blob/master/lib/joint.rb#L18

Comment: I think is an issue with how how Padrino handles attachement uploads in Rails when you upload a file you get a ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object, that repsonds_to original_filename.

Answer (score 1):

See my comments above:

Here's my thought on what you need to do, I think you need to modify the params so that params[:background][:file] is the tempfile object, like so:

```
params[:background][:file] = params[:background][:file][:tempfile]
background = Background.create(params[:background])
```

I'm not 100% sure on this, but if this doen't work I could setup a quick Padrino app and test.